# how to draw a line follow the ball on animation,like Discovr app?

Tags: objective-c, animation, core-animation

How to draw a line follow the ball on animation,like **Discovr** app ?

I want to make a app like **Discovr**,have some balls float and connect by lines.

How can I redraw the lines when the balls are moving?

I use `UIView Animation` on the balls.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a CAShapeLayer. A shape layer takes a CGPath, and will animate changes to the path as long as the changed path contains the same number of points/lines/arcs.

You could animate the movement of your balls and create an animated change to the shape layer that moves the endpoints of the lines at the same time.